# Побитовые операторы

Tags: любой-язык, битовые-операции

Как выполняются побитовые операторы, если одно число двухзначное, например `10(2)`, а второе- трехзначное, `110(6)`. При `10 | 110` получилось `110`, и я решил что к `10` справа добавляется `0`, получается `100 | 110`. соответственно в результате получается `110 (1 на 1 = 1, 0 на 1 = 1, 0 и 0 = 0)`, потом при `10 & 110` я ожидал, что снова добавится к `10 -> 0, 100 & 110`, будет равняться `100 (1 на 1 = 1, 0 на 1 = 0, 0 и 0 = 0)`. но консоль в качестве результата выдала `10...`

Comment: Вы когда делаете обычные вычисления с обычными числами, тоже как-то так считаете? `12 + 3 = 12 + 30 = 42`?

Comment: ааа, наверное, все таки добавляется слева? Написал, потом пришло в голову )) 010 | 110 == 110, 010 & 110 == 010 => 10, все верно..

Comment: Ну да, конечно, добавление нулей слева числа не изменяет, а вот справа - изменяет. :)

Comment: [Читаем, наслаждаемся](https://learn.javascript.ru/bitwise-operators).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Операция побитового "или" (|) определена так

```
0 | 0 = 0
0 | 1 = 1
1 | 0 = 1
1 | 1 = 1
```

Операция побитового "и" (&) определена так

```
0 & 0 = 0
0 & 1 = 0
1 & 0 = 0
1 & 1 = 1
```

- Если в аргументах более одного разряда, то операция выполняется независимо для каждого разряда
- Если аргументы имеет разную разрядность, то к более короткому слева добавляются нули

Итого:

```
 10 |      10 &
110       110
----      ----
010 |     010 &
110       110
----      ----
110       010
          ----
           10
```

Comment: _Если аргументы имеет разную разрядность, то к более короткому слева добавляются нули_ — слишком сильное утверждение. В общем случае не верно.

Comment: @wololo Контрпример?

Comment: [Контрпример](https://ideone.com/AQFuAK).

Comment: @wololo Согласен. Надо переформулировать. Не соображу как

Comment: Ну, вопрос задан с меткой "любой-язык". Но поведение битовых операций всё-таки определяется конкретным языком. Если более короткий операнд отрицательное число, то при "расширении" до более широкого операнда слева вполне могут добавляться единицы. Это обусловлено кодированием отрицательных чисел [дополнительным кодом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4).