# Побитовое и,или

Tags: c

Помогите.Не совсем понимаю как это работает.

`x = x & 0x01;
 x = x | 0x01;`

Comment: [Зачем нужны побитовые операторы и что они фактически делают в Си?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/100851/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%A1%D0%B8)

Comment: [Побитовые операторы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787862/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B)

Comment: Что *именно* вам тут непонятно?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Зачем нужны побитовые операторы и что они фактически делают в Си?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/100851/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%a1%d0%b8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Для справки: префикс 0b означает, что число будет представлено в двоичном формате, в свою очередь 0x означает, что число будет представлено в шестнадцатеричном формате. В данном случае 0x01 будет совпадать со значением 0b01, но вот числа 0x11 и 0b11 уже имеют различные значения*

Покажу на примере: 
Если x = 0b00, в случае конъюнкции (&) с 0b01 ответ будет 0b00: при конъюнкции разряды, стоящие в одинаковых местах перемножаются (не совсем так, конечно) между собой. 
Тогда при x = 0b01 в случае конъюнкции с 0b01 мы получим ответ 0b01.

```
0b00 & 0b00 = 0b00;  
0b00 & 0b01 = 0b00;  
0b01 & 0b00 = 0b00;  
0b01 & 0b01 = 0b01;
```

А вот дизъюнкция (|) больше похожа на операцию сложения:
Если к x = 0b00 мы применим операцию дизъюнкции с числом 0b01, то получим число 0b01.

```
0b00 | 0b00 = 0b00;  
0b00 | 0b01 = 0b01;  
0b01 | 0b00 = 0b01;  
0b01 | 0b01 = 0b01;
```

Answer (score 0):

Пусть x - целое число, например 10. Запись 0x01 эквивалента 1, что в логике,как и в си, означает истину.

---

Число 10 в двоичной системе выглядит так: 1010. А теперь мы для каждого бита этого числа делаем логическую операцию с заданным выражением (т.е. с единицей).

Рассмотрим для начала действия с оператором И (в си - &) или конъюнкцией. Ее результат является истиной, только если оба выражения истины. (больше информации [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8A%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F))

```
1 & 1 = 1
0 & 1 = 0
1 & 1 = 1
1 & 0 = 0
```

Результаты конъюнкции - это третий столбик, т.е. мы получили число 1010, что в десятичной системе соответствует 10

Теперь для логического ИЛИ(в си - |), т.е. для [дизъюнкции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%8A%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

```
1 | 1 = 1
0 | 1 = 1
1 | 1 = 1
1 | 0 = 1
```

Теперь мы получили число 1111, при переводе в десятичную систему из двоичной мы получаем число 15

Вот [тут](https://learnc.info/c/bitwise_operators.html) больше информации по этой теме.

Answer (score 0):

Это может быть одно из двух:

1. Чтение (`&`) и установка (`|`) первого (`0x1 == 0b00000001`) бита в двоичном представлении числа `x`. Применимо, если `x` — это битовое поле, то есть совокупность `bool`-полей, упакованных до одного бита на каждое.
2. Округление (`&`) целого числа в большую сторону до ближайшего нечётного (`0 = 0b0, 1 = 0b1, 2 = 0b10, 3 = 0b11, 4 = 0b100`, ну, вы поняли), либо проверка числа на нечётность (`|`). Применимо, если `x` — это целое число, знаковое или беззнаковое (в случае знаковых чисел отрицательные кодируются переполнением: `-1 = 0b11..111, -2 = 0b11..110, -3 = 0b11..101, -4 = 0b11..100, -5 = 0b11..011`).